# Get in touch with IT Administrators for Website upgrades

Tags: untagged

My company has created a charting component designed to work with "technical specs" pages on websites, so we would like to contact *Website Administrators*, so we can propose our component for integration into their websites. It has to be someone who has enough *technical know-how* to understand our component, its usefulness and applicability, and who has access to the site *via FTP*. Any idea how we can contact such people? *System Administrators?* or *IT Admins?* Whom and How?

I was thinking of these business communities such as LinkedIn and FaceBook but I don't know whether the people there would be in charge of their company's website or whether they would be willing to listen to my proposal. Our component is very straight forward to integrate so its shouldn't be a problem *convincing* them, after we get in touch. This is a long-term marketing strategy so *any* help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Technical know-how is all fine and dandy, but even if it's the slickest thing ever created - you should promote it based on the business value it adds. What does it do to the web site that makes it a better web site? Then go for the CCO (dunno the english title, the communications officer role thingie).

Comment: English title you're looking for would be CTO or CIO most places.

Comment: This is way out of the scope of questions defined in the [FAQ], and to be blunt, Server Fault is not here to help you do targeted spamming.  I suggest you consider contacting Stack Exchange re: advertising on sites like webmasters.stackexchange.com - I don't know what their rates are, but I have to assume they're pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you advertise on sites like Server Fault oder Stack Overflow? Seems to be the perfect place to get in touch with IT administrators.

Since your potential customers are a global community, a good alternative would be to pay for [Google Adwords](http://adwords.google.com/). You'll have to [choose some good keywords](http://www.google.com/sktool/) to reach the right people.

Comment: Ideally something that's cheap, like communities of such people we can contact for free.